# How to copy text file to unreal blueprint array

Tags: unreal-blueprint

I want to copy text file array( 1 2 4 1 5... , delimiter is space or enter or can edit in other program )
in to unreal blue print.

I've typed numbers directly into the array.

Comment: Please read [ask]

Answer (score 0):

To read files you can use C++ code and encapsulate it in a Blueprint node. After, you only need to "cut" the string. Maybe this tutorial help you:

https://bocilmania.com/2017/03/12/reading-text-file-in-unreal-engine-4/

UE4 have many string functions and you can find it in UE4 documentation:

https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/BlueprintAPI/Utilities/String/index.html

I encourage you to seek help first there.